# how to validate SharePoint:formfield

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, jquery

I have a data view web part and it does insert,delete ,in edit mode it save and cancel button.The data is based on a custom list.In the list i have set the max to 4 but in DWP it doesn't seem to work.
    When in Edit mode or in Insert mode i want to validate this field

```
<SharePoint:formfield runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Quantity" ItemId="{@ID}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Quantity')}" />
```

I want make sure the number being added is not greater that 4.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: please let me know how did you validated it. I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
I used the function PreSaveAction() to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a customfield

and overrides the validate method

[create custom field control](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981226.aspx)

```
public override void Validate()
{
   //make your validation here

}
```

Comment: Thanks but i did this using Sharepoint Designer.
If i did build it in Visual Studio i could have taught of that earlier I need something on the client if it exists.